# UIScrollView with UITextView Subview Scrolls To The Top When TextView Appends a New Line

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uitextview

Some background about my view. Its a scrollview with a couple of UITextFields and one UITextView at the bottom. The reason its in a scroll view is so when the user selects a field, for example their phone number, the view will scroll to the middle of the screen. Everything related to the text fields is working great. My issue is related to the UITextView.

The text view has a defined height of greater than or equal to 40 and has scroll turned off. This is so when the user adds more text than can fit on one line the text view will grow in size. This is functional as well.

The issue occurs when the user selects the text view, the scroll view centers the text view and then the user proceeds to enter text till it hits a new line. At the point where the newline is added the scroll view scrolls to the top of the view.

It seems to me that it is related to auto layout adjusting the content size and setting the content offset to 0,0. I did manage to get the scrolling to return to where it was using viewDidLayout and resetting the content offset but it causes the view to flicker as auto layout resizes the views and the scrolling occurs. Is there a method I can use to set the content offset when the scroll view content size resizes?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, are you seeing a similar issue?

Comment: Fixed it with sizeToFit